# Add 2 Datetime + 1 BIT Columns to MS Access DB

Tags: ms-access-2013

```
ALTER TABLE Warranty ADD COLUMN StartDate2 DATETIME, EndDate2 DATETIME, Status2 BIT
```

This isnt getting me far - I even tried to break it down like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Warranty ADD COLUMN StartDate2 DATETIME
```

But get an error saying 
"*The following errors were encountered while parsing the contents of the SQL pane: ALTER TABLE Warranty ADD COLUMN StartDate2 DATETIME. The query cannot be represented graphically in the Diagram and Criteria Pane.*

I should note that I did try to add the columns in MSAccess itself but my Visual Studio's didnt update after a refresh. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In Access you can do:

```
Currentdb.Execute ("ALTER TABLE Warranty ADD COLUMN StartDate2 DATETIME")
```

So call the same command from VS if that is what you want.